# Create Contact from PHP

Tags: api

Whats wrong with this code?
After submitting my form, I want to create a new contact in CRM via PHP, but it returned 500

```
$result = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'Create', [
    'where' => [
        ['first_name', '=', $_POST['first-name']],
        ['last_name', '=', $_POST['last-name']],
        ['email', '=', $_POST['email']],
      ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use api4 explorer (http://{site}/civicrm/api4) to generate that? You probably mean `values` instead of `where`.

And to do Email you'll need to chain: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/chaining/

Comment: No, I'm created it by myself, When I try to follow this link it goes to 404 (http://{site}/civicrm/api4) and (http://{site}/wp-admin/civicrm/api4). 

Where I can see the name of the fields and everything connected with them, such as e-mail chaining?

Comment: And when I replace "where" to "values" and drop the "email", returns all the same 500. $result = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'Create', [
        'values' => [
            ['first_name', '=', $_POST['first-name']],
            ['last_name', '=', $_POST['last-name']],
          ],
        ]);

Comment: I found worked URL - {my_site}/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fapi4#/explorer/Contact/